# Cross-compiler on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS under Linux Subsystem for Windows

Tags: 64-bit, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build and run my cross compiler (which is 32-bit), and I am unable to execute the binary, I get an *Exec format error*.

`file` and `readelf` claim that it is a 32-bit executable, but `ldd` disagrees. What am I missing here? The same procedure is working on RedHat-based hosts.

```
$ ./arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
bash: ./arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

$ ldd arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
not a dynamic executable

$ file arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, stripped

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 1):

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13377507-please-add-32-bit-elf-support-to-the-kernel

and here is the answer. 32-bit precompiled binaries do not work under the linux subsystem for Linux.

Comment: Do you mean "the Linux subsystem for *Windows*"?